# Does Ultimaker Cura account for the printhead in the print space?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I'm currently trying to print a really tall item that is somewhat width dependent (it's a dice tower, so I can't make it too small or thin or the dice won't travel through it properly) and it reaches the very top of the space designated for printing in Cura. By eye and looking at my printer (Wanhao Duplicator i3), I'm worried that the printhead won't be high up enough towards the end of the print to print the top of the tower, and don't really want to print something for 8 hours to find out.

Is this not a problem as Cura accounts for it, or is it worth slicing up the model, printing it in two or three parts, and then gluing them back together? I plan to sand it and paint it afterwards anyway, so any seams wouldn't necessarily be too much of an issue, I would just worry about messing with the geometry enough to make the print fail.

I should note I have already downsized the tower by about 30% to fit it in to my available print space. :-)

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the settings for your printer in Cura have the same build volume?

Comment: @agarza , I’ve just been using the pre-made settings for my printer that Cura has given me and haven’t had any problems so far but I’ve never printed anything particularly tall before

Comment: Compare your settings to the build volume stated by the manufacturer.

Comment: @agarza, I've done this, the height of the build volume in Cura and the height given by the manufacturer are the exactly the same (180mm for reference). Will it be okay on the last millimetre or should I work in a tolerance of 1-2mm?

Comment: The slicer should warn you if the model is too tall for the build volume of your specific printer. If you feel that it necessary to work in a tolerance, that would be up to you.

Comment: Got it, thank you :-)